# How to handle inconsistence state using Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, amazon-dynamodb, spring-batch

in my spring batch application, CustomItemWriter has to update value in two separate tables(DynamoDB). If one table update is successful and some exception occur in updating the second table then the update from the first table should also be rollbacked(that either both update should be successful or none).

I am using following spring batch configuration

```
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />


    <bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>
```

How can I achieve this. Is there any support provided by spring batch. Does we should use something else other then MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean?

Answer (score 0):

All the operations in DynamoDB are atomic. So, multiple operations can't be clubbed together to manage in a transaction. DynamoDB doesn't provide this feature natively like RDBMS.

However, AWS has a wrapper [library](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions) for this.

Other **alternative solution** would be to use DynamoDB stream to update the second table.

1) Create a DynamoDB stream on table 1
2) Once the item is updated successfully, it produces a stream
3) You can consume the stream record to update the table 2

[Dynamodb stream example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-triggers-streams-lambda-cross-region-replication-app/)